# Scikit-learn PCA issue: cannot finish, kernel dies

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I have a dataset with all numeric data as the shape of: `(1873, 64)`

There is no NaN, inf, and -inf values exist in the dataset:

```
X.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
X.dropna(inplace=True)
```

I want to reduce the dimensionality to 1/3 column size, which is around 20 dimensions by using `sklearn.decomposite.PCA()`.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(20, random_state=111)
pca.fit(X)
```

Then the fit cannot finish as I have waited for more than 6 hours.

So I tried

```
pca.fit(X.head(200))
```

Then I get
`The kernel for xxx.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically.`

If I try

```
pca.fit(X.head(100))
```

I can get some result without error.

Can anyone help me to identify the issue and figure out how to do the PCA properly?

Comment: Maybe you need more RAM?

Comment: it's a memory error. did you try `ulimit -s unlimited`